# using LINQ inside a function 

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

```
 public List<NDT_Equipment> GetALLRecords()
    {
        using (NDT_DB)
        {
            return (from a in NDT_DB.NDTEquipment select a);
        }
    }
```

- where : NDT_DB - class instance of the autogenerated database context class
        NDT_Equipment - partial class inside the database context class
- what I want :

  - return all records from table NDTEquipment
- what Im getting : 
  " are you missing a cast " error everytime I compile ..

question : 
  - am I allowed to use the NDT_Equipment partial class as a return value to be used in my VIEWMODEL ??? or I need to create a specific class to contain the results from this LINQ statement and that class is to be used in my VIEWMODEL ?

Comment: It's not really a "partial class." All the partial refers to is the fact that part of the definition of the class may be in multiple CS files, to be honest. It's a full fledged type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really need to use the features provided by `List<NDT_Equipment>` I would change the signature of the method to return `IEnumerable<NDT_Equipment>` instead:

```
public IEnumerable<NDT_Equipment> GetALLRecords()
{
    using (NDT_DB)
    {
        return (from a in NDT_DB.NDTEquipment select a);
    }
}
```

**Update**
There seems to be something strange in the code though; the generic type argument in the method is `NDT_Equipment` while the data entity is called `NDTEquipment`; are you specifying the correct type argument? If you point at `a` in your code, what type is it reported to be? That is the type you should have in the generic type argument.

Comment: - im getting "are you missing a cast" error if I changed it to IEnumerable

Comment: @Dennis: see my updated answer. (edit: I see now that @Anders picked up that as well; will leave my answer though, as an alternative solution)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
return (from a in NDT_DB.NDTEquipment select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<NDT.Models.DataAccess.NDTEquipment>' to System.Collections.Generic.List<NDT.Models.DataAccess.NDT_Equipment

Comment: Seems you have two different classes then, NDTEquipment and NDT_Equipment.

Comment: Anders .. you ARE RIGHT .. its my stupidity .. i have another class defined as NDT_Equipment ( which intelisense offered firts when I was codin) and the class I wanted which is NDTEquipment (without the underscore) 
thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting the error because the LINQ statement doesn't return a List (which your method signature states). Try changing this line:

```
return (from a in NDT_DB.NDTEquipment select a);
```

To:

```
return (from a in NDT_DB.NDTEquipment select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200445/using-linq-inside-a-function/2200468#2200468

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink - In SO, we have problems with duplicate questions, not answers.

Comment: @Oded: I agree, but in this case, we have 3 answers that a) are valid responses b) are the same c) arent the solution because the questioner messed up. I fail to see what the two misleading duplicates add. But I understand how hard it is to delete a duplicate once one has had an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ query is returning an [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx), not a list, so you need to convert it to a list first:

```
return (from a in NDT_DB.NDTEquipment select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200445/using-linq-inside-a-function/2200468#2200468